# Electron builder can't open output file

Tags: node.js, electron, builder, electron-builder

I have tried to use Electron Builder to build Windows installer. However, I just can build one time, but when I install it throws error:

[image: error]

I tried to build it again, but this time it throws error:

```
makensis: 
Output: "\Users\hoangha\HaLink\service-oriented-architecture-assignment\desktopApp\~Desktop\\SOA Library Setup.exe"

makensis: Can't open output file
Error - aborting creation process

Finished makensis with code 1
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/cli.js:30
    throw error;
          ^
Error: makensis failed
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/lib/win.js:81:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

And here is my config.json file:

```
{
  "osx" : {
    "title": "SOA Library",
    "background": "assets/osx/installer.png",
    "icon": "assets/osx/mount.icns",
    "icon-size": 80,
    "contents": [
      { "x": 438, "y": 344, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
      { "x": 192, "y": 344, "type": "file" }
    ]
  },
  "win" : {
    "title" : "SOA Library",
    "icon" : "icon.ico"
  }
}
```

Do anybody know how to solve this problem? WHere did I do wrong.

Comment: Did you find a solution? i have this problem too.

Comment: Actually I have not fixed it yet, however there is also discussion about this issue on the main repository, you can check it out: https://github.com/loopline-systems/electron-builder/issues/44